# Python3 RSPI3 Serial Object Programming

Tags: python, object, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, at-command

I'm using today for a project a [GSM/GPRS RSPI module](https://www.itead.cc/wiki/RPI_SIM800_GSM/GPRS_ADD-ON_V2.0). My job is to send, with AT commands, files to a FTP server (it's working by a simple program in Python or with putty by sending all AT commands one by one).

Today, to simplify my code, i chose to translate the code in object.
Also, i create my class with all my methods like send SMS, connectGPRS, sendFTP... (these methods do not appear to simplify the code)

But when i'm launching my program, i don't receive my confirm's reply from the module.

When `isReady()` start, the program send serial command to test the module. But i don't have any reply. My serial port configuration seems like right (`debug()` return ttyAMA0), and i can control my module by using Putty. But when i'm doing a short circuit with Tx and Rx, i can't see the request from the program on Putty.

Then my program stop in line `sys.exit(0)` with `ser.isReady()` returning false.

So my question is : It is possible to use Serial port, like i used it, in object programming ? Or do i make a mistake in my code ?

Regards. (sry btw for my frenchglish)

```
import serial

print("Reset du module")
resetModem()
time.sleep(5)

ser = ConnexionModule(SERIAL_PORT, 9600, 5)

if not ser.isReady():
    print("Failed reboot, maybe a another program connected on serial, or the device isn't lauched")
    sys.exit(0)

#debug() is a print function
def debug(text):
    if VERBOSE:
        print("Debug:---", text)

# This class is in reality in a another file imported in main
class ConnexionModule():
    def __init__(self,serial_port,baudrate,timeout):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baudrate, timeout)

    # Testing if the module is ready to be used
    def isReady(self):
        # Resetting to defaults
        cmd = 'ATZ\r'
        # When i send 'ATZ' the module return 'OK'
        debug("Cmd: " + cmd)
        self.serialwrite(cmd,2)
        reply = self.ser.read(self.ser.inWaiting())
        reply = reply.decode("utf-8")
        time.sleep(8) # Waiting for a reply
        debug("Reply: " + reply)
        return ("OK" in reply)

    def serialwrite(self,cmd,slp):
        debug("Sending:")
        debug(self.ser.port)
        debug(cmd)
        self.ser.write(cmd.encode())
        time.sleep(slp)
```

This code working :

```
import serial

print("Reset du module")
resetModem()
ser = serial.Serial(SERIAL_PORT, baudrate = 9600, timeout = 5)
if not isReady(ser):
    print("Fail reboot")
    sys.exit(0)

def isReady(pserial):
    # Resetting to defaults
    cmd = 'ATZ\r'
    debug("Cmd: " + cmd)
    serialwrite(pserial,cmd,2)
    reply = pserial.read(pserial.inWaiting())
    reply = reply.decode("utf-8")
    time.sleep(8)
    debug("Reply: " + reply)
    return ("OK" in reply)

def debug(text):
    if VERBOSE:
        print("Debug:---", text)

def resetModem():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(P_RESET, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(P_RESET, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(P_RESET, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(P_RESET, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Why you have this line `Thread.__init__(self)` while you don't actually importing the package nor you are using it throughout your code?

Comment: Oh, i didn't saw it. This one was a copy and paste from a classThread, but i didn't see it have been pasted too. Ty for your reply.

Comment: I deleted this line, but i have the same result, i do not receive the reply from my module.

Comment: I think you just need to cut and past the entire class definition right after `import serial` line. The class need to be loaded before you creating an instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in reality, the class is in a lib file. I past my code to simplify like this. It's a error when we execut it from stackOverflow but, on my side, it's not comming from this part.